# Invisible images in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I have created a help html document and linked it to context and toc help in eclipse plugin.The context help works perfectly whereas in the table of contents view (toc) the same page appears without any traces of images. All the images are invisible and there are no red crosses even. Anybody have faced this scenario ? Your suggestions are most welcome.

Thanks,
Santhosh

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix for the issue. The help document was .htm format. We will prepare a help word document and generate the .htm document out of this. This is done for the ease of editing the help document via Word.

It was inferred that eclipse E4 Help extension does not recognize the img tags of .htm format.But the tags of .html format were recognized properly.

Hence use .html format for help in E4 even though .htm works well will eclipse 3.x versions